# How do I map H and L to scroll by one screen if the cursor in already on the top line or bottom line

Tags: key-bindings, scrolling

Basically map H and L based on the cursor positon. If I press H the cursor should go to top of the screen and if I press H again I want to scroll up by one page.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a fantastic idea! I might steal this for my own `.vimrc`... :P

Anyway, this can be done with `<expr>` mappings. I also found [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6176012/3524982) extremely helpful. Onto the solution...

```
nnoremap <expr> H getcurpos()[1] == line("w0") ? "\<PageUp>" : "H"
nnoremap <expr> L getcurpos()[1] == line("w$") ? "\<PageDown>" : "L"

xnoremap <expr> H getcurpos()[1] == line("w0") ? "\<PageUp>" : "H"
xnoremap <expr> L getcurpos()[1] == line("w$") ? "\<PageDown>" : "L"
```

Basically, the way this works is by first evaluating a vimscript expression, and running the resulting string as a sequence of normal mode keys. The expression is

```
getcurpos()[1] == line("w0")
```

Note that `getcurpos` seems to be a vim 8 feature. If you're on an older vim and you don't have this, you could do `getpos('.')` instead.

`getcurpos()[1]` will give you the current line number, and `line("w0")` will give you the first visible line and `line("w$")` will give you the last visible line.

---

Further reading...

- [`:h <expr>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-<expr>)
- [`:h getcurpos()`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/23921432369e210029a26864cfb4f1537b3c3395/runtime/doc/eval.txt#L4437)
- [`:h line()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#line())

Comment: Can also just use `line()`. e.g. `nnoremap <expr> H line('.') == line("w0") ? "\<PageUp>" : "H"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works in regular vim8. One other suggestion to your answer is to put the cursor on the top line after <PageUp> and on the bottom line after the <PageDown> so that its easier to scroll pages. But unfortunately, I just started using Spacevim as it comes with tons of plugins and somehow the H and L move the cursor to the fourth line from the top and fourth line from the bottom. I guess I have to figure out how to disable it. I would be greatful, If any one can help me.

Comment: You probably have scrolloff set.  That is the vertical distance in lines to keep the cursor from top or bottom of the display.

Answer (score 1):

I use a non-zero value for `'scrolloff'` so this one handles `&scrolloff > 0` and has a few other small enhancements compared to DJMcMayhem's fine submission:

- Incorporates a suggestion that I like from [this comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14204/how-do-i-map-h-and-l-to-scroll-by-one-screen-if-the-cursor-in-already-on-the-top?newsletter=1&nlcode=701806%7c7f5c#comment24386_14205) to keep the cursor at the top/bottom of the screen after paging up/down.
- Uses `line()` rather than `getcurpos()` for consistency and to avoid any potential compatibility issues with `getcurpos()` and earlier versions of Vim
- Uses the more Vim-like (to me anyways) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

.

```
nnoremap <expr> H line(".") - &scrolloff == line("w0") ? "\<C-B>H" : "H"
nnoremap <expr> L line(".") + &scrolloff == line("w$") ? "\<C-F>L" : "L"
```

Similarly for `xnoremap`.